# How to move items owned by user A to a new folder, without moving items owned by other users

Tags: bash

I have a large folder, with about 30k images. Many are owned by user A. I want to move those  items owned by user  A, while leaving the rest un-touched. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way is using `find`, Within all it options yo can use `-user` to determine which owner the actions are executed on. So in your case, you should use something like this

```
find /path/where/find/files -user `id -u yourUser` -exec mv -vf {} /destination/path/ \;
```

You can accurate your search by adding, for example `-type` or `-name` options

```
find /path/where/find/files -type f -name "*.jpg" -user `id -u yourUser` -exec mv -vf {} /destination/path/ \;
```

That means like; *find here (/path/where/find/files) all files (only regular files) that end with ".jpg" and when you find them move it to /destination/path*

`find` it's a very usefull tool, [here a tutorial](https://www.booleanworld.com/guide-linux-find-command/) that explains the basics.